# How to put a Menu bar and a chart in the same scene

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

hey guys  i am an it student and i just started javafx and i need help.
i have created a class that allows me to generate a Menubar and a chart they both work in an independent way, but my probleme is how to add the Menu bar at every chart bar class, so i can navigate easly between the charts i have really been looking for it, and it most be done tonight

and this is the source code

```
    package mto.cr.GUI;
     import java.util.logging.Level;
     import java.util.logging.Logger;
     import javafx.application.Application;
     import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
     import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
     import javafx.event.EventHandler;
     import javafx.scene.Scene;
     import javafx.scene.control.*;
     import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
     import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
     import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
     import javafx.stage.Stage;

   public class MenuMain extends Application {

Stage window;
BorderPane layout;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Crowd Rise");

    //statistique menu
    Menu statisqueMenu = new Menu("Statistique ");

    //Attribution Experience declaration setonaction et add dans le menu
    MenuItem attributExperience = new MenuItem("Attribution Experience");
    attributExperience.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Statistique1 st1=new Statistique1() ;

          st1.start(window);




        }
    });
    statisqueMenu.getItems().add(attributExperience);
    //financement projet
     MenuItem FinancementProjet = new MenuItem("Financement Projet");
    FinancementProjet.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    }
    );
    statisqueMenu.getItems().add(FinancementProjet);
    //projet
     MenuItem projet = new MenuItem("projet");
    projet.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    });
    statisqueMenu.getItems().add(projet);
    //separeteur avec un trait
    statisqueMenu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
    //user
    MenuItem user = new MenuItem("User");
    user.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    });
    statisqueMenu.getItems().add(user);


    statisqueMenu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
    statisqueMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Exit..."));

    //recherche menu
    Menu rechercheMenu = new Menu("Recherche");
    //user
     MenuItem userR = new MenuItem("User");
    userR.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    });
    rechercheMenu.getItems().add(userR);
    //projet
     MenuItem projetR = new MenuItem("Projet");
    projetR.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    });
    rechercheMenu.getItems().add(projetR);        
    //probleme
    MenuItem problemeR = new MenuItem("Probleme recherche");
    problemeR.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    });
    rechercheMenu.getItems().add(problemeR);






    //Main menu bar
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(statisqueMenu,rechercheMenu);

    layout = new BorderPane();
    layout.setTop(menuBar);

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 400, 300);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}

}
```

And i also have another class that allows me to create a chart and this is the source code

```
    package mto.cr.GUI;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
    import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class Statistique1 extends Application {

@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    MenuMain menumain=  new MenuMain();
    menumain.start(stage);
    stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
    //defining the axes
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
    //creating the chart
    final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
            new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

    lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
    //defining a series
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName("My portfolio");
    //populating the series with data
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));
    Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
    lineChart.getData().add(series);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot launch more than one `Application`. This is why you should seperate any code you want to use independent from the `Application` to classes not extending `Application`. Also you have repetitive code, which makes it harder to maintain the code (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)).

Since your intention seems to be to replace the center node of the `BoderPane`, I recommend creating factory classes for the content to be displayed in the center instead of `Application` subclasses and creating a function for creating the menus items:

```
MenuItem createMenuItem(String text, final Supplier<Node> factory) {
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem(text);
    item.setOnAction(evt -> {
        setContent(factory);
    });
}

void setContent(Supplier<Node> factory) {
    Node content = factory.get();
    layout.setCenter(content);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Crowd Rise");

    //statistique menu
    Menu statisqueMenu = new Menu("Statistique", null, 
                                      createMenuItem("Attribution Experience", new Statistique1()),
                                      createMenuItem("Financement Projet", new Statistique2()),
                                      ...);

    ...
```

```
 public class Statistique1 implements Supplier<Node> {

    @Override
    public Node get() {
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        return lineChart;
    }

}
```